# Dynamically setting argument to function annotation

Tags: python

I have a `util.py` file that contains some utility functions that I import in my main script with `from util import *`. Some functions in `util.py` are annotated with a third-party annotation like this:

```py
NUM_CLASSES = 10

@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[NUM_CLASSES], dtype=tf.uint8)))
def normalize(sample):
    #some logic
```

Now I have the case that I want to set `NUM_CLASSES` dynamically from my main script before I call it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why specify `input_signature` at all?

Comment: Because it [reduces retracing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function#input_signatures_2) when tensors have dynamic shape. The example above is redacted and in reality: `input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float64), tf.TensorSpec(shape=[NUM_CLASSES], dtype=tf.uint8))`